# Hierarchyid datatype using Varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a table, Have a columns like DepartmentCode and ParentDepartmentCode which 
 are of varchar(5) columns.
The sample values of DepartmentCode are like 1,123,ABC,DEF

I am trying to create HierarchyId datatype column using above. When creating hierarchy as /1/123 it is fine,however when creating hierarchy as /1/ABC it is throwing error as below. So i wonder can't we use string data in HierarchyId?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Department](
[GLDHierarchyID] hierarchyid NOT NULL
)
insert into Test_Department([GLDHierarchyID]) select hierarchyid::GetRoot();
insert into Test_Department([GLDHierarchyID]) select hierarchyid::Parse('/'+ 
cast(1 as varchar(4))+'/');
select [GLDHierarchyID].ToString() from [Test_Department]

--This works good
Declare @testData varchar(3)='123'
Declare @hiearchy hierarchyid 
SELECT @hiearchy=[GLDHierarchyID] FROM [Test_Department] where 
[GLDHierarchyID].GetLevel()=1
INSERT INTO Test_Department([GLDHierarchyID]) 
SELECT  
Case when try_parse(@testData as int)>0 then 
hierarchyid::Parse(@hiearchy.ToString()  + cast(cast(@testData as int) as 
varchar(5))+'/')
else hierarchyid::Parse(@hiearchy.ToString() + cast(@testData as varchar(5)) 
+'/')
end as GLDHierarchyID
--select [GLDHierarchyID].ToString() from [Test_Department]

--This does not work
Declare @testData varchar(3)='ABC'
Declare @hiearchy hierarchyid 
SELECT @hiearchy=[GLDHierarchyID] FROM [Test_Department] where 
[GLDHierarchyID].GetLevel()=1
INSERT INTO Test_Department([GLDHierarchyID]) 
SELECT  
Case when try_parse(@testData as int)>0 then 
hierarchyid::Parse(@hiearchy.ToString()  + cast(cast(@testData as int) as 
varchar(5))+'/')
else hierarchyid::Parse(@hiearchy.ToString() + cast(@testData as varchar(5)) 
+'/')
end as GLDHierarchyID
--select [GLDHierarchyID].ToString() from [Test_Department]





Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or 
aggregate "hierarchyid": 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24001: SqlHierarchyId.Parse 
failed because the input string '/1/ABC/' is not a valid string 
representation of a SqlHierarchyId node.
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OrdPath.InitFromString(String chDottedString)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.Parse(SqlString input)
.
```

Comment: Did you check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference ... it seems to be ok with string but you have to use .ToString().

Comment: Yes i checked. ToString() method is once hierarchy is created, to convert hex notation to string format. My question is creating hierarchy itself using string data

Comment: From the referenced documentation: "For levels underneath the root, each label is encoded as a sequence of **integers** separated by dots." You could convert "ABC" and "DEF" from/to hexadecimal, but I get the feeling that a "G" will come along soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference) says:

> A slash starts the representation, and a path that only visits the root is represented by a single slash. For levels underneath the root, each label is encoded as a sequence of integers separated by dots. Comparison between children is performed by comparing the integer sequences separated by dots in dictionary order. Each level is followed by a slash. Therefore a slash separates parents from their children.

So, you can have things like `/1/1.2/3.17/`, but that's about as exotic as it gets.

I've had good luck doing a slash-separated list of IDs. It has the added benefit of being self-documenting (i.e. you could re-create the path yourself).